# Smooth variable frame-rate (video)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, video-streaming

I have a motion-jpeg decoder that I wrote for viewing ip-camera streams. It works great, I can easily achieve over 30 fps with multiple devices. My problem is that these frames can come in bursts over the network.

What I'm trying to achieve is a formula for averaging the time between frames to get a more steady playback. Currently, my frames are put into a ConcurrentQueue from the network thread, and the most recent frame is displayed on the UI thread. Below is my current code for smoothing the video stream, but it doesn't work as I planned...

**PlaybackFrame**) Class holding BitmapImage -> "*Image*"
**base.getFrame()**) retrieve *PlaybackFrame* from ConcurrentQueue

```
    private const int MAX_FRAME_DELAY = 500;
    private const float RATE_FACTOR = 0.1f;

    private long last_frame_time;
    private long last_update_time;
    private float rate;

    //=============================


    public override bool Get(out BitmapImage image) {
            PlaybackFrame f = null;
            if (base.getFrame(out f)) {
                long now = Environment.TickCount;
                if (last_frame_time > 0) {
                    // Get # of frames in buffer
                    int count = getCount();
                    //
                    // Get duration since last update & last frame displayed
                    int update_duration = (int)(now - last_update_time);
                    int frame_duration = (int)(now - last_frame_time);
                    //
                    // estimated delay based on current frame-rate
                    float target_rate = 0;
                    if (count > 0) target_rate = update_duration / (float)count;
                    //
                    // offset actual delay/rate by current value
                    last_update_time = now;
                    rate = lerp(rate, target_rate, RATE_FACTOR);
                    //
                    // [backup] if duration exceeds 0.5 seconds, display next frame
                    if (frame_duration >= MAX_FRAME_DELAY) {
                        image = f.Image;
                        last_frame_time = now;
                        return true;
                    }
                    //
                    // if duration exceeds delay, display image
                    if (frame_duration > rate) {
                        image = f.Image;
                        last_frame_time = now;
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        // too soon, wait...
                        image = null;
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    // first image, display
                    last_frame_time = now;
                    image = f.Image;
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                // no image available
                image = null;
                return false;
            }
        }

        private float lerp(float a, float b, float f) {
            return a*(1f - f) + b*f;
        }
```

Comment: Why not use a buffer?

Comment: Could you be more specific? The ConcurrentQueue acts as a buffer holding the list of incoming images. I'm looking for a way to delay the display of those images, based on the incoming frame rate.

Comment: Pause the video whenever the buffer has less than X next frames.

Comment: Or more precisely, when the buffer is empty, pause and show "loading..." until there are at least X frames ahead.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I think you've misunderstood my goal. I'm currently receiving between 10 & 30 frames per second, but sometimes the frames will pause for short moments, then come very quickly (think of clamping a water hose & then releasing it). Showing a 'loading' or 'paused' dialog would interrupt this video stream. What I'm looking for is a way to create a variable delay to smooth out the incoming video frames. I have tried to do this with the code above, by interpolating the incoming frame rate, but it is not working properly.

Comment: Fixing the low fps for short periods of time can't come from your own code, there must be a problem someplace else or more likely the connection is unstable or of poor quality. You could calculate the time needed to wait on the fast frames to achieve the same slow speed, and wait that time out as needed, if you want stable low fps. If you want stable high fps, you must have *more* frames in advance before starting to play them. But if the play rate is higher than the receive rate, you will inevitably have to either lag or pause (or force stable low fps)

Comment: That is why I specified using a variable/adaptive rate. Yes, I do want to slow down the frame-rate during the bursts, but only if there was a delay before-hand. Anyway, I was able to figure it out myself, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake. I was computing my time measurements within the *base.getFrame()* method, which only executes if a frame is available. By moving the measurements outside of this block, they are updated on every render event, creating a smooth time-step based on the number of frames available within the buffer.

- Still needs to be cleaned up, but working great...

  ```
  private const int MAX_FRAME_DELAY = 500;
  private const float RATE_FACTOR = 0.01f;

  private long last_frame_time;
  private long last_update_time;
  private float rate;

  //=============================

  public override bool Get(out BitmapImage image) {
      PlaybackFrame f = null;
      long now = Environment.TickCount;
      if (last_frame_time > 0) {
          int count = getCount();
          //
          int update_duration = (int)(now - last_update_time);
          int frame_duration = (int)(now - last_frame_time);
          //
          float target_rate = 0;
          if (count > 0) target_rate = update_duration / (float)count;
          //
          last_update_time = now;
          rate = lerp(rate, target_rate, RATE_FACTOR);
          //
          if (frame_duration >= MAX_FRAME_DELAY) {
              if (getFrame(out f)) {
                  rate = MAX_FRAME_DELAY;
                  last_frame_time = now;
                  image = f.Image;
                  return true;
              } else {
                  image = null;
                  return false;
              }
          }
          //
          if (frame_duration > rate) {
              if (getFrame(out f)) {
                  last_frame_time = now;
                  image = f.Image;
                  return true;
              } else {
                  image = null;
                  return false;
              }
          } else {
              image = null;
              return false;
          }
      } else {
          if (getFrame(out f)) {
              last_frame_time = now;
              image = f.Image;
              return true;
          } else {
              image = null;
              return false;
          }
      }
  }

  private float lerp(float a, float b, float f) {
      return a*(1f - f) + b*f;
  }
  ```